# how to use templete(theme) jquery js file in artical in joomla3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, joomla, joomla3.0

i am using joomla 3.2 and i am facing the issue that i am using online java compiler in  my artical and i am using min.js file which file is same as using by my theme so i want to use theme js in my artical for compiler
below is my problem images:

[templete's js files](http://screencast.com/t/5ENJDKdT8YNr)  --- templete js file load during opening artical

[my artical js file](http://screencast.com/t/5ENJDKdT8YNr)  ---artical's js files

[compiler working good](http://screencast.com/t/Mqx0dWD7)  ----- working compiler

as you can seen in artical js file that i have to load same js file for my compiler which i have it in my templete js
NOW,REAL Problem is
if i remove the link ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js from artical compiler

then problem like this :

[without load js in artical for compiler](http://screencast.com/t/MUDXzAaC0q)

[Compiler not working](http://screencast.com/t/nhewYdYzIjE)

You can check my live site

[Working compiler link](http://joomla5.guru99.com/java-user-defined-exception.html)

[not working compiler link](http://joomla5.guru99.com/first-java-program.html)

You can check js file's by source view button

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link of your templet file instead of jquery link